# How to store value of QR code in Firebase

Tags: android

Hi I'm currently doing a bicycle rental apps with MIT app inventor. May I know how can I store the decoded QR code Value in Firebase?

Answer (score 0):

Even though your question is unclear, I would try to answer your question in the simplest manner.

To store and retrieve QR Code data using firebase, you can do the following steps.

**Steps**

1. Create a Project in your Firebase console and set up your Android Project accordingly.
2. Once the project is set up, you can add QR Code reader in your app, which scans the QR Code and gets some data. Usually, it is unique-id along with other relevant data.
3. Once you get the data of the scanned QR Code, you can save this in the Firebase Database. I would recommend adding timestamp along with this data for future requirements

You can find some helpful links below:

1. [Read and Write Data on Android using Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write)
2. [QR Code Scanner Library (ZXing)](https://github.com/zxing/zxing)
3. [QR Code Scanner Library (Code scanner)](https://github.com/yuriy-budiyev/code-scanner)